# Not adding a collection and data to React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im triying to add data to fireStore with a non-existing database called `user`. Howeverimplemented it in the code. Still I'm not seeing any data inside the database...

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { BsPersonBadge } from "react-icons/bs"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword ,updateProfile } from "firebase/auth"
import {auth ,storage,db} from '../../firebase'
import {  ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { setDoc ,doc } from "firebase/firestore"


function SignUp() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [err , setErr] =useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
       const displayName = e.target[0].value
       const email = e.target[1].value
       const password = e.target[2].value
       const file = e.target[3].files[0]
  
      

    try{
      const res = await  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    
      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          setErr(true)
      
        }, 
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
            await updateProfile(res.user,{
              displayName ,
               photoURL:downloadURL
              })
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users",res.user.uid), {
              uid:res.user.uid,
              displayName,
              email,
              photoURL:downloadURL
            }).catch((error) =>{
              console.log(error)
            });
        
          });
          
        }
      )
      navigate('/login')
    }
    catch(error){
      setErr(true)
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
 
  return (
   <section className='w-full min-h-screen text-white flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-b from-neutral to-slate-900'>
        <div className='card lg:card-side bg-slate-900 '> 
            <div className='card-body flex items-center justify-center'>
              <BsPersonBadge style={{color:'#ce024d', height:'auto',width:200}}/>
            </div>
              <div className='divider divider-primary divider-horizontal sm:divider-vertical'></div>
              <div className='card-body mx-auto'>
              <h1 className='text-4xl text-center'>Register</h1>
              <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form-control card-body text-black gap-4'>

              <input type="text"  placeholder="Display Name " className="input input-ghost input-md  input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />

              <input type="email"   placeholder="Email" className="input input-ghost input-md input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />

              <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" className="input input-ghost input-md input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
           
              <input type="file"    className="file-input file-input-sm file-input-ghost text-white file-input-accent w-full max-w-xs" />
              <div className='card-actions '>
                <button type='submit' className='btn btn-md btn-accent'>Sign Up</button>
              </div>
              <p className='text-white'>Already have an account?<span className='link link-accent' onClick={()=>navigate('/login')}>Login</span></p>

              </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
   </section>

  )
}

export default SignUp
```

> > > the `users` should be created for the first time and the `...params` should be added but still  no luck..

Comment: can you show you complete component where you calling this function?

Comment: There are some inconsistencies with your data, especially with `displayName` and `email`. It should be `key: value` pair. Similar with `uid:res.user.uid` and `photoURL:downloadURL`. You may check this link on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).